# Big Theta Proof Tightness

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, asymptotics

I found that $n_0 = 1 $ and $k=5$ for Big Oh, but I am somewhat confused on how to prove big omega as I have a negative sign in my expression. Furthermore by showing big oh and big omega, am I showing big theta automatically or do I have to take additional steps? Can anyone show me how to formally solve these types of proofs?

Answer (score 1):

Big $\Omega$, $\Theta$, $O$, is, without additional context, an "eventually" criterion.

$$4\cdot n^2 < 5n^2-7n < 5 \cdot n^2$$

is *eventually* always true as $n\to\infty$.

So $5n^2-7n \in \Theta(n^2)$

Edit: It is correct etiquette to explain why you down-vote an answer. So please do so

Comment: is it enough to show that 4n^2 < 5n^2 -7n for big Omega?

Comment: Yes, note that $n^2 \ge 7n$ for all $n\ge 7$

Comment: Any care on telling me why this is voted down? Its as per Wikipedia's definition

Comment: It wasn't me, but maybe the downvote was for using the singular "criterion" with the plural "are"?

Comment: We'll see. Grammar tyrants of peace.