# Prove the big theta

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, asymptotics, computer-science

I need to find a $n_0$ and $k$ for Big Oh and an $n_0$ and $k$ for Big Omega, to find a big theta bound for:

$5n^2 - 9n = \theta(n^2)$

Can anyone help me and show me how to find these for this example? (An upper and lower bound).

Comment: I just did this here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949021/big-theta-proof-tightness/949029#949029